# Express.js routes with Typescript

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, typescript1.6

I want to use [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) with Typescript to specify the code more modular/OO.

I want to implement a Route/Controller by implementing the IRoute interface and then adding the new Route to app.use().

The problem I'm facing is that each operation (get,post,put,delete) itself returns the IRoute interface and I'm not sure what to return to. To return 
`return <IRoute> this;` in an operation is not working.

The typescript compiler response with the following error message:

> Class MessurmentsController incorrectly implements interface IRoute. Types of property `all` are incomatible. Type `(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => void` is not assignable to `type (...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute`. Types of parameters `req` and `handler` are incomatible. Type `Request` is not assignable to type `RequestHandler`.

```js
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import {IRoute, Request,Response}  from 'express';


export class MeasurementsController implements IRoute {
 path: string;
 stack: any;
 
 constructor(){
  this.path = "/api/measurements"
 }
 
 
 all(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
  res.send('');
        //return <IRoute> this;
 }
 
 get(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
  res.send('');
 }
 
 post(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
  res.send('');
 }
 
 put(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
  res.send('');
 }
 
 delete(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
  res.send('');
 }
 patch(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
  res.send('');
 }
 options(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
  res.send('');
 }
 head(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function){
  res.send('');
 }
}
```

The Route in d.ts is defined as

```js
    module e {
        interface IRoute {
            path: string;
            stack: any;
            all(...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute;
            get(...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute;
            post(...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute;
            put(...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute;
            delete(...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute;
            patch(...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute;
            options(...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute;
            head(...handler: RequestHandler[]): IRoute;
        }
```

Any Idea of what I need to return in an operation to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally a solution emerged:

routing-controllers
Allows to create controller classes with methods as actions that handle requests. You can use routing-controllers with express.js or koa.js.
https://github.com/pleerock/routing-controllers

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you.

```
export class Admin implements IRoute {
    path: string;
    stack: any;
    constructor() {
        this.path = '/api/Admin';
    }

    all(handerl: RequestHandler): any {
        return <IRoute>this;
    }
    get(handerl: RequestHandler): any {
        return <IRoute>this;
    }
    post(handerl: RequestHandler): any {
        return <IRoute>this;
    }
    put(handerl: RequestHandler): any {
        return <IRoute>this;
    }
    delete(handerl: RequestHandler): any {
        return <IRoute>this;
    }
    patch(handerl: RequestHandler): any {
        return <IRoute>this;
    }
    options(handerl: RequestHandler): any {
        return <IRoute>this;
    }
    head(handerl: RequestHandler): any {
        return <IRoute>this;
    }
}
```